# Can I deploy a Ruby on Rails webapp to an IIS webserver?

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, iis

Can I deploy a Ruby on Rails webapp to an IIS webserver?

Is there any solid support for this somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Fast CGI for Ror](http://roriis.codeplex.com/). You can also find instructions [here](http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/02/18/10-steps-to-get-Ruby-on-Rails-running-on-Windows-with-IIS-FastCGI.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's Ruby Implementation for the .NET Framework, [IronRuby](http://IronRuby.Net/) contains the [`IronRuby.Rack` adapter](https://GitHub.Com/IronRuby/IronRuby/tree/master/Merlin/Main/Hosts/IronRuby.Rack/#readme), which lets you run *any* Rack-based web application, including Ruby on Rails apps, but also Sinatra, Merb, Camping and others on IIS.

Unfortunately, there's no pre-compiled binary yet, but here's [a nice screencast that walks you through compiling the Rack adapter](http://IAmNotMyself.Com/2010/04/22/RunningRailsInIIS7WithIronRubyRack.aspx) and deploying a simple app on IIS.